# ASP.NET MVC 4, EF5, Store additional data in many to many junction table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, code-first

I have a Code First MVC 4 Web app - there's a many to many relationship between Places:

```
public virtual int PlaceID { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<User> Followers { get; set; }
```

and Users:

```
public virtual int UserID { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Place> Places { get; set; }
```

Users can 'follow' many places, places can have many followers.

I would like to store additional information about the relationship - say a rating. So a user could have a rating for each place they follow, of between 1-10, say.

How can I achieve that - including CRUD operations (Code First, Entity Framework 5).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to replace the many-to-many with two one-to-many relationships to an intermediate class that has the rating property which could be defined as below (you may need to add navigation attributes):

Create an intermediate class

```
public class UserPlaceRelationship {
  public virtual int PlaceID { get; set; }
  public virtual int UserID { get; set; }
  public virtual Place Place { get; set; }
  public virtual User User { get; set; }
  public virtual int Rating { get; set; }
}
```

Update your places class:

```
public virtual int PlaceID { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<UserPlaceReationship> UserRelationships { get; set; }
```

and your users class:

```
public virtual int UserID { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<UserPlaceReationship> PlaceRelationships { get; set; }
```

Querying will be a little trickier as you will have to now navigate through the intermediate class.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I could leave the many-to-many as is, and create a separate structure to record the additional data? Would that be a good approach?

I like the convenience and simplicity of the existing relationship (eg using Place.Followers.Count to get a total count of all followers). If not how would I query with this setup?

Comment: No - the right answer (for 3NF) is the two one to many's. If you wanted to know the total followers for a place you could still count the relationships (as there would be one relationship per person per place) so Place.UserRelationships.Count would still give you the count of followers

Comment: Thanks - so to clarify, in what way would this be a bit more tricky? For example?

Answer (score 0):

You must create a junction table and add extra info to it.

Till now, there is no way to create a CRUD  master-detail controller with related views.

You should follow the answer I provided to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17850710/1814343) question of yours...

Comment: sorry I've temporarily had to move off this project. When I am back on it in a few weeks I will clean up these questions - currently I'm not in a position to accept any answers but certainly will.