# How can I use EF to add multiple child entities to an object when the child has an identity key?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

We are using EF5 and SQL Server 2012 the following two classes:

```cs
public class Question
{
    public Question()
    {
        this.Answers = new List<Answer>();
    }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping is as follows:

```cs
public class AnswerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Answer>
{
    public AnswerMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.AnswerId);

        // Identity
        this.Property(t => t.AnswerId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}
```

Database DDL

```sql
CREATE TABLE Answer (
    [AnswerId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Text] NVARCHAR(1000),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Answer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AnswerId] ASC)
);
```

Here are the results of what I have tried:

**This works for one child:**

```cs
var a = new Answer
{
    Text = "AA",
    QuestionId = 14
};
question.Answers.Add(a);
_uow.Questions.Update(question);
_uow.Commit();
```

**This does not work for more than one child:**

Error: An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

```cs
var a = new Answer
{
    AnswerId = 0,
    Text = "AAA",
    QuestionId = 14
};
var b = new Answer
{
    AnswerId = 0,
    Text = "BBB",
    QuestionId = 14
};
question.Answers.Add(a);
question.Answers.Add(b);
_uow.Questions.Update(question);
_uow.Commit();
```

**This does work for more than one child:**

It creates AnswerID's 1000 and 1001 but I want new Id's to be created by the database.

```cs
var a = new Answer
{
    AnswerId = 1000,
    Text = "AAA",
    QuestionId = 14
};
var b = new Answer
{
    AnswerId = 1001,
    Text = "BBB",
    QuestionId = 14
};
question.Answers.Add(a);
question.Answers.Add(b);
_uow.Questions.Update(question);
_uow.Commit();
```

**Does not work:**

Compiler error. Can't convert null to int

```cs
var a = new Answer
{
    AnswerId = null,
    Text = "AAA",
    QuestionId = 14    
};
var b = new Answer
{
    AnswerId = null,
    Text = "BBB",
    QuestionId = 14
};
question.Answers.Add(a);
question.Answers.Add(b);
_uow.Questions.Update(question);
_uow.Commit();
```

**Doesn't work:**

ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

```cs
var a = new Answer
{
    Text = "AAA",
    QuestionId = 14
};
var b = new Answer
{
    Text = "BBB",
    QuestionId = 14
};
question.Answers.Add(a);
question.Answers.Add(b);
_uow.Questions.Update(question);
_uow.Commit();
```

In my application, I have one or more new Answer objects generated on the client and then these are sent to the server. Above **I am simulating what will happen** without adding the client into the question. Note that the adding of all Answers to the Question object is done on the client and then comes over in a JSON string to the server. It is then deserialized to a Question Object like this:

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage PutQuestion(int id, Question question) {
    _uow.Questions.Update(question);
    _uow.Commit();
```

I want each Answer objects to be created with a `new identity ID`, for these to be added to the Question object and for the Question object to be returned back in the normal way.

I don't know how this can be done. All my simple tests so far don't work. Please note this is a variation on an earlier question by our group member which was less clear and which I am trying to close. This question is I hope more clear.

Notes:

Here is the way update is coded:

```cs
public virtual void Update(T entity)
{
    DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
    if (dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached)
    {
        DbSet.Attach(entity);
    }  
    dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding Answer a twice?

Comment: Syntax error - fixed now. Thanks for pointing this out. The actual code tries to add an "a" and then "b" variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mentioned that you are adding `a` two times...?!

```
question.Answers.Add(a);
question.Answers.Add(a);
```

Usually, to add items which their id is identity, you must skip setting the id. You also should add the `[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute to these IDs:

```
public class Answer
{
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

And add data like this:

```
var a = new Answer{
    Text = "AAA",
    QuestionId = 14
};

var b = new Answer
{
    Text = "BBB",
    QuestionId = 14
};

dbContext.Answers.Add(a);
dbContext.Answers.Add(b);

dbContext.SaveChanges();

// ...
```

Comment: Sorry it was a typing error that I corrected. I already do what you suggest with the fluent API mapping see code above. :         this.Property(t => t.AnswerId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

Comment: Amin - My problem is that all the work is done on the client. The Answer Objects are added there to the question object. When the user clicks save this is passed to the server as a Question object complete with the new answers. I would have thought EF would have been able to manage the update of a question with new Answer objects. Maybe it's not possible in EF but it seems like a basic need.

Comment: @Alan if you want update them like this `_uow.Questions.Update(question);` you must add all old and new answers to the question and then update it...

Comment: @Amin - How can we pick out the answer objects from the question object. Update the question and then add them back? Would we have to add them back one by one to get over the problem with generating identity key values for the Answers.

Comment: @Melina That's possible, however doing that will lead you to another logical error: you'll have duplicate answers(in text) but with different IDs. Tell me what you are trying to do. Maybe I could show you another way...

Comment: Our users add Answer objects to a Question object on the client. When they click save the Question object with 0 or more new Answers is passed to the server. We then update the Question object and hopefully the new Answers with there correct AnswerIds generated by the database.

Comment: @Melina If you want a complete, reliable and errorless way, you have several works to do. See [this](http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/) to show you how. I also have some answers about this area like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17850710/1814343)

Answer (score 7):

I have run into the same identity "limitation" as well.  It turns out that if you add a parent and any children, EF can handle the fact that the parent and children are all being added together.  You run into problems when you Update the parent and insert two children at the same time.  If you attach the parent, EF will automatically pick up those two children and attach them whether you want it to or not.  Since we want it to auto generate the Id, we wouldn't set the primary key of the children.  However, EF cannot handle items with the same Primary key when the parent is an Update and blows up since both have the same PK of 0 for both children.

The only way I have found around this is to manually set the ids of the children to different numbers.  I usually set the first child's Id to -1, then -2 for the second child, and so on.  This will cause EF to save the children and the key will automatically be updated due to the Identity running on the database because -1 and -2 are not valid identity values.

However, this will cause great pain if you have a 3rd level or beyond.  Not only do you have to update this PK on each child, but then you'd have to update the FK on any of its children to this new -1 or -2 value.  Otherwise, the save will fail again!

The only other option I see is really just to insert one child at a time and call save so the context isn't dealing with more than one object with the same PK, but that kind of defeats the purpose of an ORM...

Comment: Adding [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] as suggested by @AminSaghi did not work for me, but this did. Thanks!

Comment: As of EF 6.1.2 (maybe earlier), this is no longer a problem.  It appears to work as expected now! :)

Comment: Actually, if you run through the entity tree and add all new items before attaching the updates, it works fine, too.

Comment: I know this thread is nearly three years old, but I just wanted to say that I've encountered the same problem as @DanielLorenz described while using EF 6.1.3. The only way I got around it is by inserting one child at a time

Comment: Another solution to this is to only Add all the new entities first.  Once all the Adds are done, you can go back and attach all the other items afterwards.  This is what I ended up doing to avoid assigning negative PKs all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try these things:

- use the `Create()` method of `DbSet`
- add the new instances to the `Answers` collection of your `Context`

You have set the `QuestionId` appropriately for EF to realise the relationship. Also, do not explicitly set AnswerId to zero.

```
var a = new _uow.Answers.Create();
a.Text = "AAA";
a.QuestionId = 14;
_uow.Answers.Add(a);

var b = new _uow.Answers.Create();
b.Text = "BBB";
b.QuestionId = 14;
_uow.Answers.Add(a);
```

You may need to make a call to `_uow.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` if you plan on querying the `Answers` collection of `Question` 14

Comment: The problem with this is that I am here simulating what happens on the client where the two Answer objects have already been added and appear as part of the Question object. The complete Question object comes over as JSON to the server. Because of this I cannot first create the Answer's and then add them in this way. Also I thought the whole point of EF was that it should be able to cope with this as it seems a fairly common thing to be doing. Thanks for your help / advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you have correctly declared the Id as Key and as being DBGenerated identity.
Then EF will allow you  **ADD** many of these to the context before saving.
**You can NOT ATTACH items with the same key**.
Attach is meant for offline data, put in context, set its state and save type scenarios.

*You have either used the Same instance twice and with EF tracking by default caused a mess.
Or somehow used ATTACH twice. Make sure you are handling your instances cleanly.**

eg

```
public class BaseEntityLongConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : BaseObjectLong {
    public BaseEntityLongConfiguration(DatabaseGeneratedOption DGO = DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity) {

        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        //Id is an indent allocated by DB
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DGO); // default to db generated

        this.Property(t => t.RowVersion)   // for concurrency
            .IsRequired()
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(8)
            .IsRowVersion();
    }
}
```

A just tried a simple Test to check it works (in ef5)

```
public class ExampleLog  {
    public virtual long Id   { get; set; }
    public virtual string MessageText { get; set; }
}

[TestMethod]
    public void ExampleLogTest() {
        var e1 = new ExampleLog();
        e1.MessageText = "example1";
        var e2 = new ExampleLog();
        e2.MessageText = "example2";
        _context.Set<ExampleLog>().Add(e1);
        _context.Set<ExampleLog>().Add(e2);
     var res =   _context.SaveChanges();
      Debug.WriteLine("result expected 2->" + res.ToString());
    }
```

**edit:**  At request, adding save Respository pattern,  BAsic sample, error handling removed

```
public class RepositoryBase<TPoco> : where TPoco :    BaseObject {
    public RepositoryBase(BosBaseDbContext context) { Context = context; }
```

....

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Add new POCO 
    /// </summary>
    public virtual OperationResult Add(TPoco poco) {
        var opResult = new OperationResult();
        try {
          Context.Set<TPoco>().Add(poco);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
         .... custom error tool
            return opResult;
        }
        return opResult;
    }
     /// <summary>
    /// Poco must already be attached,, detect chnages is triggered
    /// </summary>
    public virtual OperationResult Change(TPoco poco) {
        var opResult = new OperationResult();
        try {    // ONLY required if NOT using chnage tracking enabled
            Context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
         .... custom error tool
            return opResult;
        }
        return opResult;
    }
```

Comment: Phil - I have the declarations for the AnswerId in my code above but your example is very different from mine. I have a parent object which I add the children too and then I do the SaveChanges. If I follow what your example does then it works fine also.

Comment: agreed the snippet looks ok re new of instances. If that really is the code. what does _uow.Questions.Update(question);  do ?  I also assume commit just calls SAveChanges.  Then the only obvious difference is i ALWAYS use virtual on POCO props

Comment: Update does the following: public virtual void Update(T entity) {
            DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
            if (dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                DbSet.Attach(entity);
            }  
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }   Sorry about the way it displays in this comment area. Yes commit does call savechanges.  Which POCO property are you referring to. I thought all the ones that needed it were declared virtual in my code.

Comment: there the problem... attach  you CANT attach the same key twice. ill update answer to emphasize point

Comment: Thanks Phil. I added my update code to the question. Is there some other generic update that I could add to the repo and use?  If you show an answer could you make a suggestion on how I could recode thanks.

Comment: @Thanks Phil - I would look into this and at the same time look at other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

as i was going through the same issue. So thought to submit my solution.
It will be helpful for the other persons who will be searching-

```
using (var db = new EFService())
{
    var question= db.Question.Single(p => p.QuestionID == QuestionID);
    question.Answers.Add(a);
    question.Answers.Add(b);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```