# how to add multiple rows in mvc 4 and razor engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am creating finance application in mvc 4 and razor. in that there is one module Journal.
**One Journal can have multiple entries**. and ***Journal can not be created without Journal Entry***.

Following is my model

```
using Sms.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Sms.CoreSociety
{
    public class Journal : BaseClass
    {
        public Journal()
        {
            this.JournalEntries = new List<JournalEntry>();
        }
        public virtual string VoucherNo { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime VoucherDate { get; set; }
        public string VoucherDateView
        {
            get
            {
                return VoucherDate.ToShortDateString();
            }
        }
        public IList<JournalEntry> JournalEntries { get; set; }
        public IList<Ledger> Accounts { get; set; }
        public double TotalAmount
        {
            get
            {
                double sum = 0;
                if (JournalEntries != null && JournalEntries.Count > 0)
                    foreach (var journal in JournalEntries)
                        sum = journal.Principal + journal.Interest + sum;
                return sum;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following is my View

```
@model Sms.CoreSociety.Journal
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "class", "form-horizontal" }, { "id", "document" } }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span1">
                <label>
                    Voucher No</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span5">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.VoucherNo)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span1">
                <label>
                    Voucher Date</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span5">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.VoucherDate)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span1">
                <label>
                    Amount</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span5">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TotalAmount)
            </div>
        </div>
        @Html.TextBox("JournalEntries[0].AccountName", Model.JournalEntries.FirstOrDefault().AccountName)
        @Html.TextBox("JournalEntries[0].DebitCredit", Model.JournalEntries.FirstOrDefault().DebitCredit)
        @Html.TextBox("JournalEntries[0].Interest", Model.JournalEntries.FirstOrDefault().Interest)
        @Html.TextBox("JournalEntries[0].Narration", Model.JournalEntries.FirstOrDefault().Narration)

        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn" id="submit" />
        @if (Model.Id != new Guid())
        {
            <div style="float: right">
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href='@Url.Action("Delete")/@Model.Id' aria-hidden="true">
                    Delete</a>
            </div>
        }
    </fieldset>
}
<h4>
    Journal Entry</h4>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Add Entry", "JournalEntry");
```

Now I am able to get the Journal as well as **Single Journal Entry**. But my problem is I am not able to make Multiple journal entry.

[This is what i am looking for but in MVC 4 and razor without knockout.js](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to use knockout or not? That article does not include knockout.js.

Comment: i don't want to use knockout.js, i have got one exmple using knockout.js i tried that but when i deploy that code the server doesn't starts..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your goal, you need to do some extra works by jquery, ajax and partial views.

A brief example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17850710/1814343). A full howto is [here](http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/).