# In ASP.NET MVC4 - I need to edit a record and add many (1 to many) sub-records to it (while in Edit mode on the top level record)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, foreign-keys, one-to-many

Here's my list of data:

[image]

Going into Edit mode on the first record:

[image]

Here on this Edit page, I need to add multiple "Departments" to this particular contact record.  I have a 1 to many relationship (1 contact record to many department records).

Ideally, I'd like to have something like an "Add New Department" button, where the user clicks on it and it will create form fields that tie to department.  User fills them out, clicks Save, and has the option to again add another department by way of "Add New Department".

I'm not exactly sure where to start - how can I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That job can't be achieved only by mvc stuff. To achieve your goal, you need to do some extra works by jquery, ajax and partial views.

The main idea is to have a partial view to representing a detail row (when in create phase) and another partial view for getting all details of a master entity (when in edit phase).

A brief example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17850710/1814343). A full howto is [here](http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/).